What is 'ilu_tk' module in Python 1.5?
I'm trying to port Grail browser to Python 3.10+. In the source, grail.py trying to import some modules like ilu_tk, filetypes etc. which are not in the Python 1.5. Can you tell me how can I get these modules?
I've downloaded Python 1.5 and Tcl/Tk 8.0 . There are no modules such these. If anyone have ever tried to port it, give me some tips.

ILU is Xerox Inter-Language Unification, a "distributed objects" RPC system sort of like CORBA. ilu_tk is a Python module that replaces the Tkinter runloop with an ILU runloop, so that ILU RPC and a Tk GUI can be used in the same application.
It's not clear why Grail wants to do that; there's some mention of ILU having been the basis for an experimental next-generation HTTP protocol (that obviously didn't catch on, although it does bear a passing resemblance to HTTP2), but I don't see a Grail plugin to do that — or any other code using ILU at all — so it's not clear what they gain from the alternative runloop.
In any case, the ILU functionality is completely optional. It's only used if the "Enable ILU main loop" option is set in the preferences, and even then any failure to load it is ignored:
try:
    import ilu_tk
except ImportError:
    pass

which means that you should be able to ignore it (or simply remove the related code and the preference). ILU has been abandoned for 25 years and there's no advantage to using it.

Thanks a lot for your tips.
